# DllNotFoundException in ASP5/MVC6 while instantiating an object (using the WorkItemStore Class)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to instantiate the [WorkItemStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx) Class in my MVC 6 (dnx 4.5) web app but I'm getting the following DllNotFoundException error.

> An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This is my code.

```
        200Uri = new Uri("http://x contains tfs server link of company x");
        200ProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(200Uri);
        200WorkItemStore = new WorkItemStore(200ProjectCollection);
```

The more amazing thing is that the same class and code works on my previous ASP 4.5  Windows Forms app. Is this a problem with Dot Net Core? I've already switched to dnx 4.5.1 in dot net core? or MVC 6? Is this a problem with 32-64 bits library?

More details about the error-

```
System.DllNotFoundException - {"Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
Data - {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink - Null
InnerException - null
Message - Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Source: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader
StackTrace -    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative32.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection, WorkItemStoreFlags workItemStoreFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore..ctor(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at FinalApp1.Models.Config..ctor() in C:\Users\eashan\Documents\Building a Web App using ASP 5\FinalApp1\src\FinalApp1\Models\Config.cs:line 23

TargetSite - {Void CreateDatastore(IntPtr ByRef)}
TypeName - ""
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: This may be that the `Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll` is not compiled on Dot Net Core. It may not be available if you are using the .Net Core version. Try switching to .Net 4.6 and see if that works.

Comment: I'm already using .Net 4.5 for my application as I've removed .Net Core references from the project.json.

Do you mean I should not use MVC 6?

Comment: What are the 200Uri, 200ProjectCollection, and 200WorkItemStore variables? Those are illegal variable names in C#, so I am not sure how you are even building.

Comment: Apologies, those 200 were preceded by the company name, I removed it from the code sample. Thanks for all your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've managed to get it to work.I compared the build paths of my windows application form and my dnx execution environment.

Having checked the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll library using ILSpy, I found out that it did reference the Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll, which even though was present in the dnx execution folder

> C:\Users\eashan.dnx\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient\14.89.0\lib\native\x86

It did not exist in

> C:\Users\eashan.dnx\packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient\14.89.0\lib\net45
>   folder.

So, I copied the library from the first location to the other and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

## Use NuGet

1. Open the NuGet Package Manager.
2. Go to Browse.
3. Install `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`.
4. Install `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`.

[image: Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient]

Here is the resultant `project.json` file (with sections deleted for clarity.)

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient": "14.89.0",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1"
  }

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

After installing those two packages, the following code builds and runs.

```
var xUri = new Uri("http://www.somedomain.com");
var xProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(xUri);
var xWorkItemStore = new WorkItemStore(xProjectCollection);
```