# What is the build path for .Net Core/ASP5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an MVC6, .Net Core (dnx 451) web application where I've encountered a .dllnotfound exception.

Can anyone please tell me what is the build path for .net core/asp5 apps, so I can check the directory for the required .dll? Or how can I find out the build path? because it's not listed on properties window in Visual Studio?

My Project Directory -

```
C:\Users\eashan\Documents\FinalApp1

artifacts
src
FinalApp1.sln
global.json
```

I'm just looking to find out about the build path used in .Net Core/ASP5 web apps, but if anyone really wants to see more details about the error ([Posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135155/dllnotfoundexception-in-asp5-mvc6-while-instantiating-an-object-using-the-worki))

Cheers

Comment: When building from Visual Studio, it'll output to `<projectdir>/bin/<configuration>/`. If you need the NuGet packages and such, you can "Produce Outputs on Build" in the project properties.

Comment: I don't have a bin folder in my <projectdir>

Comment: You need to post more about the exception such as full error message. That can help others see what exactly the issue you met.

Comment: Are you trying to reference an external DLL?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient library. Added more details about the error if anyone needs, but I only want to find out where do .NetCore applications get built? Because I do not have a /bin folder. I think because it uses .Net Core/dnx environment?

I started from an empty web app, does that affect it?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't build directory, *ASP.Net Core* is build in memory with [*Roslyn*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)
However, you can produce binaries with [`dnu` commands](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility): `dnu build`, `dnu pack` or `dnu publish`
Check out this [Wiki page](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki) for more information

Comment: `dnu build` doesn't produce binaries

Answer (score 1):

## Specific Answers

> Can anyone please tell me what is the build path for .net core/asp5 apps...

The build path is `..\artifacts\bin\YourProjectName`.

> ...how can I find out the build path?

Open the `.xproj` file in a text editor. Look at the following sections.

```
<BaseIntermediateOutputPath 
  Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">..\artifacts\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)
</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
<OutputPath 
    Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\artifacts\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\
</OutputPath>
```

> ...so I can check the directory for the required .dll?

To view DLLs, ask Visual Studio to produce outputs on build. Step (3) is the key.

1. File > New Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application
2. ASP.NET 5 Templates > Empty
3. Properties <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> > Build > **Produce outputs on build.**
4. Build the project.

[image: Product outputs on build]

## Example Build Result

```
C:/temp/
  artifacts/
    bin/
      WebApplication1/
        Debug/
          app/
            project.json
            dnx451
              WebApplication1.dll
              WebApplication1.pdb
              WebApplication1.xml
            dnxcore50
              WebApplication1.dll
              WebApplication1.pdb
              WebApplication1.xml
            WebApplication1.1.0.0.nupkg
            WebApplication1.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg
    obj/
      WebApplication1/
        Debug/
  WebApplication1/
    project.json
    project.lock.json
    Project_Readme.html
    Properties
      launchSettings.json
    Startup.cs
    WebApplication1.xproj
    WebApplication1.xproj.user
    wwwroot
      web.config
  WebApplication1.sln
```